# Android Background Selector Pressed State Shows On All Items At Once

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have set up a background drawable selector so as to highlight the background of a list item when pressed (similarly to how I've done it many times before except the drawable is assigned in code).  First I'll show you the problem then put my code at the bottom.  If anyone can help me figure this out, I would be appreciate it!

Here the screen is waiting for input:

[image: Waiting for input]

Here I am pressing and holding down a single item.  If I slide my finger off the screen without lifting up over an item it remains just like this:

[image]

If I press and hold and then slide up to scroll the list the items that come into view are not displaying the pressed color:

[image]

Here is the relevant XML.  I set the drawable background here, but it really gets set in code so it's redundant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/thumbnail_size"
    android:background="@drawable/white_button_background">
...
</Relative...
```

Here is the drawable XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@color/stitcher_holo_blue_light" android:state_pressed="true"/>
     <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>

 </selector>
```

Here is the code where the background selector is set in an array adapter:

```
public MyArrayAdapter(...) {
    super(...);
    mItemBackground = mResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.mybuttonselector);
}

public View getView(..., View convertView, ...) {
    ...
    convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(mItemBackground);//I also tried setBackground()
    ...
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Well it's no longer an issue for me.  I changed some stuff around so that I didn't have to assign the background at run time (but just used the XML background assignment) and that takes care of it.  I'll leave the question open because I'm still wondering why this was happening and there may be situations where I have to assign it in code.